# How to bring this function out of methods inside this Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, apexcharts

I have this Vue component BarChart.vue which is from
https://github.com/apexcharts/vue3-apexcharts

The script portion of this component is as follows;

```
<script>
/* eslint-disable */

export default {
  name: "BarExample",
  data: function() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            horizontal: true
          }
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999]
        }
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "series-1",
          data: [30, 40, 45, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91]
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateChart() {
      const max = 90;
      const min = 20;
      const newData = this.series[0].data.map(() => {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      });

      const colors = ["#008FFB", "#00E396", "#FEB019", "#FF4560", "#775DD0"];

      // Make sure to update the whole options config and not just a single property to allow the Vue watch catch the change.
      this.chartOptions = {
        colors: [colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]]
      };
      // In the same way, update the series option
      this.series = [
        {
          data: newData
        }
      ];
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I want to bring updateChart() out of methods such that it is a separate function by itself.

This is what I did;

```
<script>
/* eslint-disable */

export default {
  name: "BarExample",
  data: function() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            horizontal: true
          }
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999]
        }
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "series-1",
          data: [30, 40, 45, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91]
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateChart(),
  }
};

updateChart() {
      const max = 90;
      const min = 20;
      const newData = this.series[0].data.map(() => {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      });

      const colors = ["#008FFB", "#00E396", "#FEB019", "#FF4560", "#775DD0"];

      // Make sure to update the whole options config and not just a single property to allow the Vue watch catch the change.
      this.chartOptions = {
        colors: [colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]]
      };
      // In the same way, update the series option
      this.series = [
        {
          data: newData
        }
      ];
    }
  }
</script>
```

I received an error `Parsing error: Unexpected token ,`

I am using vue3 and apexcharts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `()` like since that means that you're running the method:

```
  methods: {
    updateChart,
  }
```

or

```
  methods: {
    updateChart : updateChart,
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. Tested to work in both cases. What's the difference between the 2 ways in your answer? Which way is a better practice?

Comment: The first one is a shorthand syntax of the second one because in ES6 if the key and its value have the same name we could use the key only

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer my own question for the sake of completion as there were other syntax errors to be fixed.

I credit my answer to @Thomas in the comments section.

```
<script>
/* eslint-disable */

export default {
  name: "BarExample",
  data: function() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            horizontal: true
          }
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999]
        }
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "series-1",
          data: [30, 40, 45, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91]
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateChart,
  }
};

function updateChart() {
      const max = 90;
      const min = 20;
      const newData = this.series[0].data.map(() => {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      });

      const colors = ["#008FFB", "#00E396", "#FEB019", "#FF4560", "#775DD0"];

      // Make sure to update the whole options config and not just a single property to allow the Vue watch catch the change.
      this.chartOptions = {
        colors: [colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]]
      };
      // In the same way, update the series option
      this.series = [
        {
          data: newData
        }
      ];
    }
  
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, just wondering where my comment disappeared to...

Comment: @Thomas, I don't know who deleted it. Not me since I'm the one who credited the answer to you.